# Spring bean registeration programmatically doesnt support transaction

Tags: java, spring, rollback

my project using template service pattern.

I tried two approach.

One, using @autowired annotation.
Then, set my parameter.

Two, using AutowireCapableBeanFactory. Create ServiceTemplate programmatically then autowireBean.

My service template class is

```
public class ServiceTemplate<T>{
public ServiceTemplate(){}
public ServiceTmeplate(T clazz, ...){
...}
@Transactional
public Response someMethod(){
 try{
...}
catch{
 TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()
}
```

On my controller code is

```
@Autowired
private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanfactory

public Resonse getTest(){
final ServiceTemplate<testClass> serviceTemplate = new ServiceTemplate<>(.....)
beanfactory.autowireBean(seviceTemplate)
}
```

On my first approach, it works. It’s rollback all transaction.

But I want to take the second approach. How to make my bean under transaction manager programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second approach can't work because your `ServiceTemplate` is self-managed so spring can't proxyfied your bean with transactional concerns. Only the dependencies are managed and autowired by Spring here.

A solution is using programmatic transaction

```java
class ServiceTemplate {

 @Autowired
 private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

 private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

 public Response someMethod() {
     //
     transactionTemplate.execute(status ->     
       {
          // the code in this method executes in a transactional context
       }
    });
    //
 }
```